# jquery hide/show depending on value changed by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ship/bill form where the shipping info will be copied from the billing info through a javascript call. In the billing form, I have a few fields hidden and they change depending on the selection of the country. So far so good. However, when I fill out the bill form with country and everything (works), and then click the checkbox to have the info copied over to the ship form, it copies over the info, but it doesn't see this as a 'change' in the ship country and therefore a few fields remain hidden.

Example: I fill in as country 'USA', and therefore the state dropdown shows up with all the states. I fill in everything and hit 'copy to ship form', which is on the same page. It fills in everything to that form, but the state dropdown does NOT show up... even though there is the onchange in the country dropdown.

My code so far (sorry if this is just a hotchpotch because I use javascript and jquery both).

```
var SHIP_FNAME = "";
var SHIP_LNAME = "";
var SHIP_COMPANY = "";
var SHIP_ADDRESS1 = "";
var SHIP_ADDRESS2 = "";
var SHIP_CITY = "";
var SHIP_STATE = "";
var SHIP_ZIP = "";
var SHIP_COUNTRY = "";
var SHIP_PHONE = "";
var SHIP_CSTATE = "";

function InitSaveVariables(form) {
SHIP_FNAME = form.SHIP_FNAME.value;
SHIP_LNAME = form.SHIP_LNAME.value;
SHIP_COMPANY = form.SHIP_COMPANY.value;
SHIP_ADDRESS1 = form.SHIP_ADDRESS1.value;
SHIP_ADDRESS2 = form.SHIP_ADDRESS2.value;
SHIP_CITY = form.SHIP_CITY.value;
SHIP_ZIP = form.SHIP_ZIP.value;
SHIP_STATE = form.SHIP_STATE.value;
SHIP_COUNTRY = form.SHIP_COUNTRY.value;
SHIP_PHONE = form.SHIP_PHONE.value;
SHIP_CSTATE = form.SHIP_CSTATE.value;
}

function ShipToBillPerson(form) {
if (form.address_fillin.checked) {
InitSaveVariables(form);
form.SHIP_FNAME.value = form.BILL_FNAME.value;
form.SHIP_LNAME.value = form.BILL_LNAME.value;
form.SHIP_COMPANY.value = form.BILL_COMPANY.value;
form.SHIP_ADDRESS1.value = form.BILL_ADDRESS1.value;
form.SHIP_ADDRESS2.value = form.BILL_ADDRESS2.value;
form.SHIP_CITY.value = form.BILL_CITY.value;
form.SHIP_ZIP.value = form.BILL_ZIP.value;
form.SHIP_STATE.value = form.BILL_STATE.value;
form.SHIP_COUNTRY.value = form.BILL_COUNTRY.value;
form.SHIP_PHONE.value = form.BILL_PHONE.value;
form.SHIP_CSTATE.value = form.BILL_CSTATE.value;
} else {
form.SHIP_FNAME.value = "";
form.SHIP_LNAME.value = "";
form.SHIP_COMPANY.value = "";
form.SHIP_ADDRESS1.value = "";
form.SHIP_ADDRESS2.value = "";
form.SHIP_CITY.value = "";
form.SHIP_ZIP.value = "";
form.SHIP_STATE.value = "";
form.SHIP_COUNTRY.value = "";
form.SHIP_PHONE.value = "";
form.SHIP_CSTATE.value = "";
}
}
```

//  End -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#BILL_COUNTRY').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == 'USA')
  {
    $("#statetr").show();
    $("#BILL_STATE").show();
    $("#BILL_CSTATE").hide();
  }
  else if ( this.value == 'Canada')
  {
    $("#statetr").show();
    $("#BILL_STATE").hide();
    $("#BILL_CSTATE").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#statetr").hide();
    $("#BILL_STATE").hide();
    $("#BILL_CSTATE").hide();
  }
});

$('#SHIP_COUNTRY').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == 'USA')
  {
    $("#statetr2").show();
    $("#SHIP_STATE").show();
    $("#SHIP_CSTATE").hide();
  }
  else if ( this.value == 'Canada')
  {
    $("#statetr2").show();
    $("#SHIP_STATE").hide();
    $("#SHIP_CSTATE").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#statetr2").hide();
    $("#SHIP_STATE").hide();
    $("#SHIP_CSTATE").hide();
  }
});
});
```

(ship_cstate block is a block with the canadian states)
The checkbox is called in the code through:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="address_fillin" id="address_fillin" value="Yes" OnClick="javascript:ShipToBillPerson(this.form);">
```

I've tried to google for code to check the checkbox and then the value of the SHIP_COUNTRY, but couldn't find anything. Tried to build it myself, but that disabled the whole code basically...
I had:

```
$('#address_fillin').click(function(){
  if ($("#SHIP_COUNTRY").val("USA")) {
  {
    $("#statetr2").show();
    $("#SHIP_STATE").show();
    $("#SHIP_CSTATE").hide();
  } (etc... since this is basically a copy of the other function above)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting

```
$("#SHIP_COUNTRY").trigger("change");
```

at the end of your copy function. This will run the change function attached to `#SHIP_COUNTRY`.